# mqsql installer giving error on windows

Tags: mysql, windows

I am trying to install "`mysql-installer-community-5.7.10.0`" on windows xp sp2. However, it's giving me error *You need microsoft windows xp 3 or later".
Can anyone please help me with this.*

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. You are using **service pack 2**, while the minimum OS requirement is **service pack 3**

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Perhaps the _real_ problem is: Where to get SP3 for XP? XP is out of maintenance.